# Cannot enable Memory Intergity because of strange error

Tags: windows, security

I'm using Windows 11 Pro, and today I got a very strange error, related to the Memory Intergity feature

Okay, to the point now: I had previously enabled this Memory Intergity feature, but, now somehow, it's turned off, and when I turn it back on, the following error pops up. presently:

[image: Windows Security Picture 1]

Okay, I was able to fix the incompatible drivers, so I clicked Review incompatible drivers, but nope, there aren't any drivers listed, as shown below:

[image: Incompatible drivers view]

Here are the settings in my Group Policy, I've made sure the security options are enabled:

[image: Group Policy settings]

Even in HWiNFO64, HVCI was reported to be on in the past, but since the problem occurred, HVCI has fallen into the off state:

[image: HWiNFO64 HVCI Status]

I rebooted the system, but the same error occurred.

I also clicked Scan again, restarted the machine, then tried turning it on again, and then Scan again, 5 times, and the same error happened. I also tried Shut down, Log off, Sign out, but it didn't work

What is happening? And how to fix it?

Comment: I've read running `sfc /scannow` can resolve this - amongst many other suggestions when I searched for `can't enable memory integrity in windows 11`

Comment: I have both sfc and dism. No luck